# Is there a opposite of ^ (ends with) in mysql regex?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want a match with "word1,word2,word3" but not "word1,word3 test".

I know ^ character matches the begining of text, is there anything that I can use like "word3^"?

Comment: I would assume the $ is what you want. I have no idea why MySQL be crazy enough to change its meaning.

Comment: oh the irony that this is now the top search result for "mysql regex ends with" on google... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is matching at the end.

So probably you need this:

```
word3$
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this answer after 10 minutes.